# Tesseract doesn't seem to work with digits

Tags: tesseract

I followed the FAQ to make Tesseract recognize digits, but all I get is a bunch of text in the output file, despite having only numbers in my image.

My command line looks like this:

```
tesseract --tessdata-dir ./ ./input.jpg ./output/output digits
```

Any ideas what could be happening?.

Comment: Are you using tesseract 4.0 with LSTM? For that version you will need to use different tessdata file (trained only on digits)

Comment: I just downloaded the last version form their site, for Windows.

Comment: Is the latest version you downloaded 4.0?

Comment: Yes, from this link:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/4.0-with-LSTM#400-alpha-for-windows

Comment: 4.0-with-LSTM#400-alpha-for-windows

Comment: All right, for that version as I said earlier you can not use `digits` parameter unfortunately (as you can't black or white list any characters). Instead you should train LSTM with those chars which you need. For digits and alphas only it is already done and you can find those files in the tessdata repository.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how to do that?. Thanks.

Comment: Just use traineddata provided by Shreeshrii. Replace one from you tessdata-dir with the one (s)he created. Although that might solve your issue - I'd recommend you to use older stable versions of tesseract in production. You can use old tesseract even with your 4.0 by setting engine mode (--oem) to tesseract only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [tesseract github issue](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751) you can't black or whitelist characters with tesseract 4.0 LSTM, instead you should train LSTM with characters you expect on your image.

Thanks to [Shreeshrii](https://github.com/Shreeshrii) you can try his 'experimantal' digits traineddata from [here](https://github.com/Shreeshrii/tessdata_shreetest)

Please note that Tesseract 4.0 is still in alpha stage and if you want - you can still use 3.* versions of tesseract which support your needs from the box.
Tesseract v 3.4 tessdata is located [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/tree/3.04.00), library for windows can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Downloads)